# Ruby CGI.unescapeHTML generating strange charactors

Tags: ruby, cgi, html-encode

I have backed up a bunch of markdown formatted comments into an XML document.  This of course meant I needed to HTMLescape them.  When I try to use CGI.unescapeHTML it adds a bunch of strange characters into the markup that do not render well in all browsers.

Specifically, it replaces two spaces with "\302\240 ", but not consistently.  How do I get it to stop this behavior?

eg:

```
s = "I am seeing more and more &lt;a href=&quot;http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber /tree/master&quot;&gt;Cucumber&lt;/a&gt; usage.  This is a good thing!  But I'm also seeing people who are not using regular expressions to their fullest.  Here are some quick regex tips to keep you features readable:&#x000A;&#x000A;* `(?:a|an)` -- using a this construct you can group things wihout actually matching them.  I'm seeing a lot of steps that have unused params because someone needed a group but didn't know how to avoid capturing it&#x000A"
CGI.unescapeHTML s
# => "I am seeing more and more <a href=\"http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/tree/master\">Cucumber</a> usage.\302\240 This is a good thing!\302\240 But I'm..."
```

Comment: What version are you using? I'm not seeing it on 1.8.7.

Comment: I found out that this was being caused by Haml adding &#xA0; characters as spaces.  It works here because the SO formatting removed the problem.  It was a couple hours of work to find this though.

Answer (score 0):

Those are non-breaking spaces. [Read up on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

```
In computer-based text processing and digital typesetting, a
non-breaking space, also known as a no-break space or
non-breakable space (NBSP), is a variant of the space character
that prevents an automatic line break (line wrap) at its position.
In certain formats (such as HTML), it also prevents the
“collapsing” of multiple consecutive whitespace characters into a
single space. The non-breaking space is also known as a hard space
or fixed space. In Unicode, it is encoded as U+00A0 no-break space
(HTML: &#160; &nbsp;).
```